# Remove non-unique values from result column

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

In my SQL result I have multiple rows, each with a column that contains a non-unique list of ids.

I need to make these unique but I'm having trouble because I can't use an aggregate function on a subquery that contains another aggregate function.

This is my simplified example which results in

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

```
WITH cte_1 AS (
    SELECT  1 AS rownum,
            '1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6' as ids
)
SELECT  rownum,
        ids,
        string_agg(
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(ids,',')
            ), ',') AS ids2
FROM        cte_1
```

I would rather not use a user defined function but I suspect I may have to.

[Edit1]

For clarity, the following is the example but showing multiple rows:

```
WITH cte_1 AS (
    SELECT  1 AS rownum,
            '1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6' as ids
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  2 AS rownum,
            '1,1,2,2,2,3,5,5,6' as ids
)
SELECT  rownum,
        ids,
        string_agg(
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(ids,',')
            ), ',') AS ids2
FROM        cte_1
```

[Edit2]

For EVEN MORE clarity for those who need it, the above example common table expression contains hard coded values, but the real dataset does not.

I am not going to paste in the entire query that produces my results set as this would be counter intuitive; all I need is a way to remove the duplicate values from one column of the results, which are not actually hard coded but produced from dynamic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
WITH cte_1 AS (
    SELECT  1 AS rownum,
            '1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6' as ids
)
SELECT  rownum,
        ids,
        ( select string_agg(value, ',') ids2 FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(ids,',') ) X ) ids2
FROM cte_1
```

Comment: I'm confused, @CompanyDroneFromSector7G Why does this "work" but mine does not, when they return the exact same result set. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9215eeecb58d5b02dc5863dd0adc243b)

Comment: Yours cannot be easily applied to a results set containing multiple rows. You would need to hard code the values as you have done, but I can't do this for multiple rows where I don't know what each will be.

Comment: HUh @CompanyDroneFromSector7G How is `SELECT  1 AS rownum,
            '1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6' as ids` not hard coded values? The `VALUES` operator is for sample data.... If you want table examples, provide DDL and DML for us to use.... You could easily change the above to this [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9345700cb0a7c6bbda54fd4c4575fabd)

Comment: @Larnu Please see the bit where it says `This is my simplified example`. I'm going now, but have a great day!

Comment: My point is, @CompanyDroneFromSector7G is I dislike being told my solutions don't work, when they aren't looked at. You disregard an answer that uses "hard coded values" when you have done so yourself and declare the answer doesn't work when it does, or provides a solution for the sample you have provided but that example doesn't actually give a clear picture. You'll only deter the experts from answering your questions in the future.

Comment: Your dbfiddle doesn't work either. The result contains duplicate values.